How do you add an unbound 'select' button to an existing DAC for a custom process screen?
I have a custom process screen using the POOrder DAC as a filtered list of records to process.  The issue I'm having is how to add the 'Select' checkbox to an existing DAC?  Is that just a standard DAC extension?
If so, how would that would work when specifying the Detail View for the grid...  I can't seem  to find any examples online - the training just specifies adding the unbound (PXBool) 'Select' field directly to the existing DAC, but that's a DAC that is created in the training and not an existing stock Acumatica DAC like POOrder.

You can declare an unbound boolean DAC field named Selected as instructed.
#region Selected
public abstract class selected : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<selected> { }

protected bool? _Selected = false;
[PXBool]
[PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
public virtual bool? Selected
{
    get
    {
        return _Selected;
    }
    set
    {
        _Selected = value;
    }
}
#endregion

By naming convention Acumatica processing delegate will detect the column named Selected and will apply different behavior to it. It is possible to use a different column name by calling the processing data view SetSelected method.
public PXProcessing<DAC> ProcessingDataView;

public GraphConstructor()
{
    ProcessingDataView.SetSelected<DAC.columnName>();
    ProcessingDataView.SetProcessDelegate(ProcessingDelegateMethod);
}

Reference:
https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=18ee8457-e989-4bf0-a400-88c8fff3dfea

Selected is the default name for the data field for this specific
check box; you can define the data field with any name and override
the default Selected name in the graph constructor with the
SetSelected() method of the PXProcessing class.


I just looked and the POOrder DAC has a 'selected' field already.  Just use that

I understand - but what would you do if that didn't exist?

Just copy that field declaration from POOrder into whatever custom DAC
